# Powershell 'Optimize-Volume' Output

Tags: windows, powershell

I have written a system maintenance script which executes basic functions that retrieve statistics from a host, writes the output to a new PSObject, then finally combines the results and converts it all to a HTML web page.

I do not seem to be able to write the output of `Optimize-Volume` to the pipeline, I have to use `-verbose` - why is this? I would like to check the results of the `Optimize-Volume` cmdlet by looking for the following text which is generated at the end of the `-verbose` output, depending on the result:-

- 'It is recommended that you defragment this volume.'
- 'You do not need to defragment this volume.'

Here is the function:-

```
    function Get-DefragInfo {

    $getwmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveType = 3" | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -cne $null} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $letter = $getwmi.DriveLetter -replace ':'

    foreach ($drive in $getwmi)
    {
    $analysis = Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter $letter -Analyze
    if ($analysis -like 'It is recommended that you defragment this volume.')
    {
    $props =[ordered]@{‘Drive Letter’=$letter
              'Defrag Recommended?'='Yes'} 
    }
    elseif ($analysis -like 'You do not need to defragment this volume.')
    {
    $props =@{‘Drive Letter’=$letter
              'Defrag Recommended?'='No'}
    }


  $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

  Write-Output $obj

  }
  }
```

How do I capture the output I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell 3.0 and onward, you can use the stream redirection operator `>` to capture the Verbose ouput to a variable:

```
# Merge stream 4 (Verbose) into standard Output stream
$analysis = &{Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter $letter -Analyze -Verbose} 4>&1
# Check the "Message" property of the very last VerboseRecord in the output
if($analysis[-1].Message -like "*It is recommended*")
{
    # defrag
}
else 
{
    # don't defrag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we `Get-Help Optimize-Volume -full` we'll see the cmdlet has no output.

Some searching lead me to [this Microsoft Scripting Guys article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/15/use-powershell-to-determine-fragmentation-of-your-drive/) that pointed out using the following to check if Defrag is needed.

```
(gwmi -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'").DefragAnalysis()
```

Knowing this, we can easily make an IF Statement.

```
$DefragCheck = (gwmi -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'").DefragAnalysis() |
Select DefragRecommended

IF($DefragCheck){"Defrag recommended"}ELSE{"Defrag is not needed."}
```

It's helpful to pipe cmdlets to `Get-Member` in order to see if there are any options available.  In the above example, we can pipe `gwmi -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"` to Get-Member and find the `DefragAnalysis` method, which we use dotted notation to access (wrap the Get-WmiObject in () then use a . and the method name followed by (), it looks confusing until you try it a couple times!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I went for the verbose redirection option and it seems to be working well. My method is not the cleanest way of doing it I understand, but it works for me.

I like the second option also, I'm going to look at using this once the script is complete and functionality is proofed.

Thanks for your help once again.